# Distributed Task Scheduling, Job Queue

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2, cron

I have to email a certain task notification that needs to be sent out to users who are expecting it every 6 hours. So I have used node-cron to schedule a job on my server which wakes up every 30 min to check if any users havent responded to their emails, tracked using mysql db with updated_at col. Works fine!

But now I have to make it work in a distributed setting. Using Elastic Beanstalk with 1-4 micro ec2 instances. I dont want to add any other db/storage/queue other than what I have (MySQL).

- Can someone lay out the steps to do it in conjunction with node-cron. (Ensuring a certain task is performed once, I dont want to send notifications before my 6 hour period)
- OR do we some other library that can do this in mysql ensuring that a task is done only once
- Rather than 30 min period can I do the task when load on my server or db is not strained.
- Is there a way to do it without using db(and multiple instances), since scheduling for work in every 30 mins works fine!

To add, my api server and the worker are same.

Comment: Did you upgrade your solution (and open-sourced it)?
Or did you find an alternative?

Comment: Used a simple Timer in nodejs to do this, not pretty!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this solution developed in Python: [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org)

> *"Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed
>   message passing.  It is focused on real-time operation, but supports
>   scheduling as well."*

1. Can be integrated with several Python frameworks (Django, Pylons, ...):
   http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html#framework-integration
2. **But you prefer Node.js**, so you can use it with other languages as well, it can integrate through HTTP Callback (Webhooks):
   http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html

Comment: Thank you for replying, I am looking for some logic and guidance to upgrade my existing solution.